# Do you need exe4j if you have purchased install4j?

Tags: install4j, exe4j

I am evaluating install4j for our java based SCADA application. We seem to have some exe4j scripts in the legacy code, which are used to create .exe files. I noticed install4j also allows similar facility. Do we need to buy both install4j and exe4j or install4j is sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The license key for the install4j multi-platform edition also works for exe4j.

Comment: What about the single platform edition? Will it work for that also?